# How to get all the keys from a specific doc of a collection in firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I have already learned firestore CRUD. It is easy to get value from a document if fields are known of the doc. My question is how to grab the list of keys that the specific doc has. I need it because I want to show the fields and values in a table. If I add more fields in future in the same doc then the table will automatically be updated with the new fields and values.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs you can get a document snapshot using `get()` method of a document reference and then use `data()` method of snapshot to get all the data in the document as an object.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

```
var docRef = db.collection("users").doc("alovelace");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        // Here you can get your data
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
});
```

Then you have an object of key values representing your document data.

Comment: this code outputs only the value. but i need key (first, last , born) as output.

Comment: @Sadhon What do you mean by "only the value"? It outputs an object like `{first: "Ada", last: "Lovelace", born: 1815}`. To get the keys use `Object.keys(obj)` to get an array of keys.

Comment: If you want to get key from the object, use :const key = Object.keys(doc.data())